# com.google.android.apps.gsa.binaries.velvet.app.velvet root application keeps stopping

Tags: 7.0-nougat

I have a Samsung galaxy J7 running on android 7 I've been getting this error consistently, nothing in particular seems to trigger this error and i can't find any application with that name.
is there any way i can fix this without factory resetting ?

Comment: Your Google / Google Search app is crashing it seems. Try disabling that app and see if it solves the issue. Do note that I can't foretell what effect disabling the app would have in your phone so proceed with caution. Make a backup of important data first.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem until I updated the google (not chrome) to the latest version.

Try updating the google app once.